# Could not HEAD 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/v0.1.2/GPUVideo-android-v0.1.2.pom'

Tags: android

Im having this error :-

```
    Could not HEAD 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/v0.1.2/GPUVideo-android-v0.1.2.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Also this as the main error in logcat:-

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.MasayukiSuda:GPUVideo-android:v0.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.MasayukiSuda:GPUVideo-android:v0.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/v0.1.2/GPUVideo-android-v0.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/v0.1.2/GPUVideo-android-v0.1.2.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.github.yangjie10930:EpMedia:v0.9.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.yangjie10930:EpMedia:v0.9.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/yangjie10930/EpMedia/v0.9.5/EpMedia-v0.9.5.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/yangjie10930/EpMedia/v0.9.5/EpMedia-v0.9.5.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.github.tizisdeepan:gallerypicker:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.tizisdeepan:gallerypicker:1.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/tizisdeepan/gallerypicker/1.0.1/gallerypicker-1.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/tizisdeepan/gallerypicker/1.0.1/gallerypicker-1.0.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/shts/StoriesProgressView/3.0.0/StoriesProgressView-3.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/shts/StoriesProgressView/3.0.0/StoriesProgressView-3.0.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
18 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 11 up-to-date
```

I opened this project after sometime and when I tried to built a release it started showing this error to me I tried some other stuff but didnt work.
Can someone help me out here. It will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do as the endpoint is simply down:

```bash
$ HEAD https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/v0.1.2/GPUVideo-android-v0.1.2.pom
500 Can't connect to giphy.bintray.com:443 (SSL connect attempt failed error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading)
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2022 14:35:14 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

$ HEAD http://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/com/github/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/v0.1.2/GPUVideo-android-v0.1.2.pom
500 Server closed connection without sending any data back
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2022 14:35:21 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response
```